# Using Managed Service Accounts for Activities

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2

I know and understand the introduction of windows service accounts, and how various applications run as Windows Service Account or a virtual account. I also know that one can connect to things such a File Share etc using a Managed Service Account.

Has anyone ever tried to do anything like FTP or anything with a Managed Service Account?

If so do can you provide locations on where this information is documented.

Currently we have applications & scripts that rely on things like FTP, for doing their various jobs, these apps & scripts use, domain creds like FTPUser to connect to the FTP service. Having these domain level (user accounts) for these types of a tasks is a maintenance nightmare and a security risk. I would like to replace FTPUser with something like TRANS_APP_FTP_USER$ (Managed Service Account) so that the transfer app, will use a MSA instead of a domain account to connect to the FTP server.

So far all the docs I've seen have explained how to get the TransApp to run using an MSA... but I want the TransApp to connect to something like an FTP server.

Some documentation (links) discussing this would be helpful.